# R.java file disappers after adding images in res/drawable folder

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-xml

I am having problems after adding images into the drawable folder.

For example `R.java` file disappears after adding images in `res/drawable/xhdpi`.

After `clean` and `build` the project I am getting the error again. Naming conversion is also done correctly.

Comment: check the image name.It must follow the naming convention of Android.

Comment: clean and built your project

Comment: After clean and built the project i am getting the error again.naming conversion is also done correctly.

Comment: if you are unable to check and findout naming problem from images then show your image names here..

Comment: Check Problem tab in eclipse, it will give you the error comes in resource folder and resolve it then clean the project and check..it will work..

Comment: Naming Convention is exactly correct.
    I done Project->clean and Project->Build Project.
    I check it in website.
    Xml file is also Correct.
    Now also R.java file disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check Your Folder Location where you place the image correctly.Sometimes the image size maybe vary for xhdpi and mhdpi.So that these kind of Errors Occured many times

Answer (score 3):

Just for a simple clarification. 
You have facing problems after adding images into the drawable folder.

Before adding images, creating layouts , classes we must have to follow some rules based on documentation.

Something like

layout names must be in lowercase and class names should be starts on caps and maintain some camel case rules.

So for images
you must have to check that there is no number and capital letter is the starting letter of your image because number and capital letter is not allow as first char of resource.

Also as Sergey Pekar  said should not contain any characters which can be java operators (for example *, +, =, -).

Answer (score 1):

R.java file disappears when you clean the project with an error in layout.

You said naming convention is done properly. So now what you do is:

Build your project. If if doesn't work that way then create a new project, copy the contents and paste them. 
This should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use not allowed characters in your image file names. Each file name must start with latin letter and should not contain any characters which can be java operators (for example *, +, =, -) or non latin letters

Answer (score 0):

> Hi, If your R.java file disappears means there is some errors in your xml files, so check your last modified xml file

Answer (score 0):

The `R.java` class is used to access resources (the files in the folder `res`) and is generated at compilation time.

Whenever you clean your project the `R.java` file is deleted. In order to generate a new one you need to build the project (or just wait a moment for the class to be re-generated if your project is set to be built automatically).

If you cannot generate an `R.java` file after cleaning your project there must be something wrong with some resource. I once had a similar problem after adding an image file in the `res` folder. The file  had an unsupported filename and I got the error message `Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]` in the Console. So, for instance, `01_house.jpg` is an invalid file name while `house_01.jpg` is valid.

The solution was to:

- remove file with invalid name
- change file name to valid name and re-import it
- clean project
- build project (not needed if "Build Automatically" is checked in Eclipse)